# Phonegap Media getCurrentPosition is inaccurate and slow

Tags: audio, cordova

I have been very disappointed to find that now that I am ready to migrate my html5 app onto phones using phonegap the ability to play audio is like perpetual motion.  It is almost there, but not quite.

The answer for Androids (pre ice cream sandwich at least) is the Phonegap media api.  According to everyone.

The problem is that I REALLY care about what the current time is while playing back my audio.  On my Mac running Chrome I timed how long it takes to do:

pos=audio.currentTime

and it is less than a millisecond.

With the Phonegap media api I must call an asynchronous function, WAIT till it calls back and then I get the current media position.  This takes anywhere from 5 to over 150 milliseconds.  It is not consistent and it is distressingly slow.

It also begs the question: what time is it?  If it takes 150ms to get the time, did I get the time at the beginning of those 150ms or the end?  I really cant be sure that the time I got is really that close to the current time.

Its a good thing I am not still writing submarine navigation software, because with such a horrible source of time I would never be able to determine where I am.

I am now using the system clock to keep track of time, and using getCurrentPosition() to re-sync from time to time.  However, I can still be off by over a hundred ms.

My question: Anyone got a better approach?

EDIT:

Looking at the code for Cordova:

```
   /**
 * Get current position of playback.
 *
 * @return                  position in msec or -1 if not playing
 */
public long getCurrentPosition() {
    if ((this.state == STATE.MEDIA_RUNNING) || (this.state == STATE.MEDIA_PAUSED)) {
        int curPos = this.player.getCurrentPosition();
        this.handler.webView.sendJavascript("cordova.require('cordova/plugin/Media').onStatus('" + this.id + "', " + MEDIA_POSITION + ", " + curPos / 1000.0f + ");");
        return curPos;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

It looks to me like this should execute pretty fast...except for that call to sendJavascript().  I wonder if that is where the mysterious delay is originating?

For my purposes I don't need an onStatus event: I need to get the current position as quickly as I can.  So I wonder if I can remove that line of code...  I guess that would necessitate a change to the Cordova source itself. :(

Comment: Why don't you just use the `<audio>` element itself with standard JS?

Comment: Oh how I wish.  That is how I developed it and it works great in chrome.  Unfortunately, the <audio> tag has problems in the webkit browser which you can verify with a little searching around this site.  Basically, it doesn't give any errors, but it wont play.

Comment: Hmm. I've been developing an app with Sencha Touch and the `<audio>` element works fine in Mobile Safari. There have been a few problems with Android browser that I'm trying to resolve.